# Using digital pins 0/1 on Arduino Due when writing/reading over serialUSB port

Tags: serial, arduino-due

I am aware that you cannot use pins 0 and 1 as digital pinouts when communicating over serial via serial.print(), but what if you are using the native port on the due with serialUSB.write()?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use 0/1 while using the native USB. The two are completely separate.